# Why does solidity's try/catch not catch "call to non-contract address" revertion?

Tags: solidity, error, try-catch

Recently I encountered the issue that the `try/catch` command of solidity does not catch the revertion when I'm trying to call a non-contract address in the `try` line.

While **I'm aware of multiple workarounds for this** (such as using the `isContract` function of [Openzeppelin's Address library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/65b45726b34dafe8fc3ef78c3d4b7b3f404f61ad/contracts/utils/Address.sol#L36)), I'm still curious **what the reason for this (in my opinion) unexpected behaviour is**. Is this an "arbitrary" design decision of the solidity language / compiler ? Or is there a fundamental reason in how the EVM works that means that these revertions cannot be caught ?

Example:

Calling `callFoo` on the `Caller` contract does not revert when supplying either the `CalleeReverting` or the `CalleeIncompatible` contract addresses, but when calling it with a non contract address it will revert and not catch the error.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

interface ICallee {
   function foo() external;
}

contract Caller {
    function callFoo(ICallee callee) external returns(bool){
        try callee.foo() {
            return false;
        } catch {
            return true;
        }
    }
}


contract CalleeReverting is ICallee {
    function foo() external override {
        revert("CATCH THIS"); 
    }
}

contract CalleeIncompatible {
}
```